# Why copied file has different permissions in Linux?

Tags: linux, cp

I am logged in as root in Linux. I have a file with 777 permissions. I copied the file in the same directory with `cp`.

```
cp settings.php settings_copy.php
```

However, the copied file has different file permissions.

```
[root@localhost default]# ls -l setting*
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 29105 Apr 26 11:48 settings_copy.php
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 29105 Apr 26 09:48 settings.php
```

Is this normal? How can I ensure that the copied file gets the same permissions? I believe that it is the default behaviour for the copy command in any OS.

Comment: Check the umask settings in addition to the `cp -p` suggestions below. The umask is applied against the permissions on the copy. Especially with root, it is an important consideration. See, e.g., http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115246/file-inheriting-permission-of-directory-it-is-copied-in. This question would probably be better in the "Unix & Linux" area.

Answer (score 18):

Use the `-p` option to preserve the permissions:

```
cp -p settings.php settings_copy.php
```

When you copy a file, you are creating a new file. So, its (new file) permissions depends on the current *file creation mask*, which you change via `umask` command. Read `man umask` for more information.

Answer (score 3):

have you looked at `man cp`

This is the relevant section:

```
-p     same as --preserve=mode,ownership,timestamps

--preserve[=ATTR_LIST]
  preserve the specified attributes (default: mode,ownership,timestamps), if possible additional attributes: context, links, xattr, all
```

So to keep the same ownership and mode you would run the command:

```
cp --preserve=mode,ownership
```

If you know that's always what you want and don't want to remember it, you can add it as an alias to your .bashrc;

```
alias cp='cp --preserve=mode,ownership'
```